# How to kill Geolocation tracking in Phonegap

Tags: cordova, geolocation

I have a problem where I call Geolocation.update() to get current location. But it is a background process that keeps running .But I want to kill the process when user change the page.

I found no solution. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

```
navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(watchID);
```

Save the ID when you start the watch

```
var watchId = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(geolocationSuccess,
                                                  [geolocationError],
                                                  [geolocationOptions]);
```

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.2.0/cordova_geolocation_geolocation.md.html#geolocation.clearWatch

Comment: I am not using watchPosition. Instead I am using getCurrentPosition and have set timeout for it

Comment: Then your code has the problem and you should post your code. The only way to have this in the background, according to the documentation, is to use *watchPosition*. Per the documentation, if you are using *getCurrentPosition* the you only get one callback.